# Getting A LINQ .InsertOnSubmit To Work

Tags: linq, insertonsubmit

I'm trying to get an insert to work using LINQ and am having some difficulties.

I am using this example to base my code: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763516.aspx

I have my data object set up, but don't know what's going on when db.Orders.InsertOnSubmit is executed.

How can I create this db object to insert a data object into my database using InsertOnSubmit?

edit: Here is some code that I'm working with (It's probably a world of wrong, I'm pretty much fumbling in the dark at this point).  I'm super new to database objects, so the whole concept is a bit confusing for me.

```
var Data = new Data();
Data.value1 = 1;
var db = new dbo(connectionString);
db.InsertOnSubmit(Data);
```

Comment: Please post a short example of your code which isn't working.

Comment: Just added some example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do more than just call InsertOnSubmit(). You also need to call `SubmitChanges()`. The reason these are separate steps is to allow you to have multiple inserts, updates and deletes and then submit them all at once via SubmitChanges().

Comment: If cases where I have only one row to submit, is there a way to submit that row by calling only one function instead of calling both InsertOnSubmit() and SubmitChanges()?

Comment: No. You must call SubmitChanges(). Nothing gets persisted to the database until this method is called. Although, I suppose you could write your own Extension method that combines the two. But I don't really see the benefit in this.